# css slider using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

i want to create a image slider with title written below something like below
[image: slider image]

i want to know how can I display one image 100% while upcoming image from right to 50% with 50% hidden like in the image.please help me with some code or reference i tried but i didn't get anything about it.

so i tried with many bootstrap but i want to create with normal js function. Please use above image for reference.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this:

```js
const imageOne = document.querySelector('.imageOne');
const imageTwo = document.querySelector('.imageTwo');
const moveLeft = document.querySelector('.moveLeft');
const moveRight = document.querySelector('.moveRight');

let leftOrRight = 'left';

moveLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (leftOrRight === 'left') {
    console.log('move left')
    leftOrRight = 'right'

  }
})

moveRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (leftOrRight === 'right') {
    console.log('move right')
    leftOrRight = 'left'
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>How JavaScript Works Behind the Scenes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='imageOne'>
    <p>Foo</p>
  </div>
  <div class='imageTwo'>
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
  <button class='moveLeft'>
    <p>Left</p>
  </button>
  <button class='moveRight'>
    <p>Right</p>
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```

I didn't include how to manipulate the CSS, but that is pretty easy - you should probably just search it up if you don't know.

Comment: Sorry about the fact that I didn't add any css - I'm just kinda bad at it.

Comment: Also, did you do any research on this? It isn't a good idea to just ask a question on stackoverflow when you have an issue.